# Camel - Error with JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker when function is added to xsl

Tags: java, xml, xslt, apache-camel

I have the following stylesheet and xml:

**students.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<class>
   <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>Kad</lastname>
      <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="593">
      <firstname>Jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>Singh</lastname>
      <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

**students.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:func="http://test"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"/>

    <xsl:template match="*"><!-- matches any node -->
        <xsl:copy><!-- copies the current node and namespace nodes,NOT CHILD OR ATTRIBUTE NODES -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="student" /><!-- applies template to students elements -->
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:function name="func:marktograde">
       <xsl:param name="markarg"/>
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$markarg &gt; 90 ">
            <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="$markarg &lt; 90 and $markarg &gt; 80">
            <xsl:text>B</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:text>C</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:template match="student">
        <xsl:element name="person"><!-- renames element to person -->
            <xsl:attribute name="id-num"><!--  applies an attribute to new element called id-num -->
                <xsl:value-of select="@rollno" /><!-- copies value of student elements rollno attribute -->
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="lastname" /><!-- applies template to lastname child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="marks" /><!-- applies template to marks child nodes -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="lastname">
        <xsl:element name="student-surname">
            <xsl:attribute name="nick-name">
                 <xsl:value-of select="../nickname" /><!-- moves up a level in xml tree and copies value from nickname element -->
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- copies text value of current node -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="marks">
        <xsl:element name="grade">
            <xsl:value-of select="func:marktograde(text())" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to run this via Camel:

**SampleCamelRouter.java**

```
@Component
public class SampleCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder#configure()
     */
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        from("file:src/main/resources/input/?fileName=students.xml&noop=true")
            .to("xslt:./transforms/students.xsl")
            .to("file:target/messages/?fileName=studentsout.xml");
    }
}
```

I get this in the IDE console:

```
10:57:43,347 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - The first argument to the non-static Java function 'marktograde' is not a valid object reference.
10:57:43,349 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - The first argument to the non-static Java function 'marktograde' is not a valid object reference.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: The first argument to the non-static Java function 'marktograde' is not a valid object reference.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1020)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:791)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformerHandler(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
10:57:43,354 FATAL [main] Main  - Error with stylesheet: file:/data/userdata/Workspace/FNOL/camel-test/src/main/resources/transforms/students.xsl
org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.ConfigurationException: Error with stylesheet: file:/data/userdata/Workspace/FNOL/camel-test/src/main/resources/transforms/students.xsl
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

I've tried the xsl in a few online tools that support xsl v2, and it works fine. Whenever I try it as above, I keep getting errors despite the xsl remaining the same between the IDE and the xsl test tools. I'm using the camel spring boot starter, version 2.17.3 and version 2 xsl. I've checked a few similar questions that were answered but none seem to apply to this use case, Is there something I've left out of the xsl thats causing this?

Comment: Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor and as such will just ignore the `xsl:function` in your `version="2.0"` stylesheet. You will need to make sure you put Saxon 9 on the class path if you want to use XSLT 2.0 and `xsl:function` with Java.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks. I'm not sure if its required, but I also set saxon=true in my xslt string in the sample router